# How can I detect I'm inside an eval() call?

Tags: javascript, eval

Does there exist a string `s` such that

```
(new Function(s))();
```

and

```
eval(s);
```

behave differently? I'm trying to "detect" how a string is being evaluated.

Comment: Could you please explain why you are trying to do this? I'm curious.

Comment: @some: If you do remote debugging with Chrome, there is a function in the debugging process called `RuntimeAgent.evaluate()` where the first argument is a string that will be executed. I'm trying to figure out what is happening behind the scenes to emulate that function in the debugged process.

Comment: it is a webkit function not Chrome

Comment: @mc_fish: Do you know where I can find documentation for it?

Comment: webkit documentation or if u want the source...

http://code.google.com/p/webkit-mirror/source/browse/Source/WebCore/inspector/InspectorRuntimeAgent.cpp?spec=svne31d5917e404d48e13d3feaa9d0e8065af37ef1e&r=e31d5917e404d48e13d3feaa9d0e8065af37ef1e

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Check for the `arguments` object. If it exists, you're in the function. If it doesn't it has been `eval`ed.

Note that you'll have to put the check for `arguments` in a `try...catch` block like this:

```
var s = 'try {document.writeln(arguments ? "Function" : "Eval") } catch(e) { document.writeln("Eval!") }';
(new Function(s))();
eval(s);
```

[Demo](http://pastehtml.com/view/ca61zq8sa.html)

[Solution to `nnnnnn`'s concern.](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/yA4dL/2/) For this, I've edited the eval function itself:

```
var _eval = eval;
eval = function (){
    // Your custom code here, for when it's eval
    _eval.apply(this, arguments);
};

function test(x){
    eval("try{ alert(arguments[0]) } catch(e){ alert('Eval detected!'); }");
}
test("In eval, but it wasn't detected");​
```

Comment: What if the eval statement is inside another function? http://jsfiddle.net/yA4dL/

Comment: @nnnnnn Good point. I'm not sure there's a way now. I'll add it to my answer if I find a way.

Comment: @nnnnnn Added a solution to that.

Comment: Cool. Can you please explain why that new fiddle works? (Note: eval needs to return a value. And [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) recommends against calling eval indirectly.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Sure thing. Making it go through another function changes the scope it has access to. This sort of breaks `eval`'s functionality if the `eval` requires access to the variables in the current scope. Since now your string is going to `eval`, the new function, `_eval` has access to the variables in the global scope. In this case, there is no `window.arguments`, so it throws an error which lets us detect that it's been `eval`ed.

Comment: Is there any way to safely hook eval function in Node.js?

Answer (score 15):

The current answer does not work in strict mode since you can't redefine eval. Moreover, redefining `eval` is problematic for many other reasons.

The way to differenciate them is based on the fact that well... one of them creates a function and what doesn't. What can functions do? They can `return` stuff :)

We can simply exploit that and do something with `return`:

```
// is in function
try {
     return true;
} catch(e) { // in JS you can catch syntax errors
     false; //eval returns the return of the expression.
}
```

So in example:

```
var s = "try{ return true; }catch(e){ false; }";
eval(s); // false
Function(s)(); // true
(new Function(s))(); // true, same as line above
(function(){ return eval(s); })(); // the nested 'problematic' case - false
```

Comment: well. this is an interesting way to do it, but fails if one wants to detect if one is in an eval, and do something if not - the return would return and nothing would be done.

Comment: hmm. actually this isn't working in any case... even putting the "return" in a "try", trying to eval is giving me "SyntaxError: Illegal return statement"

Comment: Is there any way to safely hook eval function in Node.js?

Answer (score 2):

evaled code can be detected by invoking an error and checking if the native stack-trace contains a lower row/column indicator.

```js
if (typeof window === 'object') {
    // browser
    window.isEvilEval = function () {
        return parseInt(String(new Error().stack).split(':').pop(), 10) < 10;
    };
} else {
    // nodejs (must be global to be callable from within Function)
    global.isEvilEval = function () {
        return (
            new Error().stack
                .split('\n')
                .filter((l) => l.trim().startsWith('at eval') && l.indexOf('<anonymous>:1') > -1).length > 0
        );
    };
}

// test - directly in code => false
console.log(isEvilEval());

// test - in evil eval => true
eval('console.log(isEvilEval())');

// test scoped in function => false
Function('console.log(isEvilEval())')();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.