# Ways to evaluate a string

Tags: javascript

Given a string `s`, how can one "execute" it in JavaScript?

I know of two ways, namely `eval(s)` and `(new Function(s))()`.

Are there other ways in which a string can be evaluated?

Comment: You can write a Javascript interpreter in Javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227546/how-can-i-detect-im-inside-an-eval-call

Comment: @Kundan: I don't see the connection.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Yes, but what technique would the interpreter end up using?

Comment: @Random: Well, parsing and executing. What an interpreter does. V8 doesn't have access to `eval` either.

Comment: @NiklasB.: And the executing would be done using... `eval`, something else? That's my question.

Comment: @Random: I think you don't understand how an interpreter works :P Usually if you write one, you don't have an implementation ready to use, so of course you couldn't use `eval`. Instead, you have to define the logic yourself

Comment: For examples, see [Narcissus](https://github.com/mozilla/narcissus/) or [Js.js](https://github.com/jterrace/js.js) or others.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Ah. Well I'm restricting myself to a browser environment, say Google Chrome's javascript runtime, in which case I can only use what I'm given...

Comment: @Randomblue: My point still applies, you can use a Javascript interpreter written in Javascript in any Javascript-aware environment (including V8). I still don't see the point of your question, though

Comment: What is "s"? What it is also depends on the answer that can be given.

Comment: @epascarello: It's a string containing JS code?

Comment: My point was if it is JSON, you could use JSON.parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML document, you can create `<script>` element, but I don't think `<script>.innerHTML` will work in all browsers (but it does in Firefox).

```
var strToEval = "window.alert(1);";
window.onload = function() {
        var scrEl = document.createElement('script');
        scrEl.innerHTML = strToEval;
        document.body.appendChild(scrEl);
};
```

Or, instead of setting `innerHTML`:

```
scrEl.src = "data:text/javascript," + strToEval;
```